# How can I fix this broken RF connector?

Tags: rf, connector

I have a broken RF connector.  If I soldered it in place, would that work? I am not an engineer and don't know if it needs ground or soldering the connecting interface together would work.

[image: Broken RF Connector]

Comment: It might work. But it would be delicate. If you want to replace the PCB jack, we can help you identify it. We would need good pictures of both mates and dimensions: OD of the PCB jack and total mated height of both connectors.

Comment: Please show a picture of the mating connector.

Comment: Pretty good photo +1

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the connector would solve your problem. But do you have the skills needed to do this? If not you might have a associate that does, talk to that person. I do not know where you are but many areas have repair shops that could do that at a very reasonable cost. The hardest part will be in finding the correct replacement connector. Another possible a more inexpensive solution is to replace the board.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is a U.FL connector on a u-blox GPS board, which can be sourced from multiple locations.

[image]

*(Image from potential source referenced below.)*

It might be possible to solder back, but it will remain very weak.

One option is source a new connector ([cheap and easy to find](https://thepihut.com/products/ufl-smt-antenna-connector)) and solder in place.

A quick alternative (which depending on your soldering skills might be easier) is to strip off the end of your U.FL pigtail (i.e. remove the U.FL connector entirely, and expose a short length of core along with a twisted bit of the braid), and solder that directly to the two pads on the PCB.  If you glue the coax to the PCB, this should solve your problem.

You could also do this with an SMA connector on a pre-prepared pigtail to give you a socket you could use with a range of external antenna.

Comment: Make sure it's a U.FL and not W.FL or X.FL or whatever-else.FL. Similar-looking connectors come in a number of different sizes, so you'll need to measure to make sure you get the right size.

Comment: Agree. I was suggesting ufl based on a number of similar boards, but do need to check.